# ActivatedRoute does not update the child route data on route changes

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular8, angular-activatedroute

I'm tying to get the child route data('layout') from parent component using `ActivatedRoute`. I have tried the following example and I'm able to get the data I'm looking for but only for one time. During child route changes, I don't see the updated 'layout' value.

**Routes**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: Layout1Component,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: './pages/analytics/analytics.module#AnalyticsModule',
        data: {
          layout: 'boxed'
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'files',
        loadChildren: './pages/files/files.module#FilesModule',
        data: {
          layout: 'full'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

**Layout1Component**

```
export class Layout1Component implements OnInit {
  constructor(private service: AppService, route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.layout = route.snapshot.firstChild.data['layout'];

    route.url.subscribe(() => {
      console.log(route.snapshot.firstChild.data['layout']);
    });
  }
}
```

I want the console.log to be printed with updated 'layout' value every time the route is changed.

Please help me fix this.

Answer (score 13):

From my understanding, the reason why you're getting the data only once is because `ActivatedRoute` gets the `url` as a **BehaviorSubject** when it is instantiated.

```js
function createActivatedRoute(c: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
  return new ActivatedRoute(
      new BehaviorSubject(c.url), new BehaviorSubject(c.params), new BehaviorSubject(c.queryParams),
      new BehaviorSubject(c.fragment), new BehaviorSubject(c.data), c.outlet, c.component, c);
}
```

[*Here's the link for the above snippet*](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/create_router_state.ts#L77-L79)

This means that when you subscribe, you'll only get that first stored value.

One way to solve it is to make use of the **router events**.

Assuming you have something like this:

```js
const routes: Route[] = [
  { 
    path: '', 
    component: HelloComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'foo',
        loadChildren: () => import('path/to/foo').then(m => m.FooModule),
        data: {
          name: 'andrei'
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'bar',
        loadChildren: () => import('path/to/bar').then(m => m.BarModule),
        data: {
          name: 'john'
        }
      },
    ]
  },
]
```

Here is a possible solution:

```js
 constructor (private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

 ngOnInit () {
    const routeEndEvent$ = this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd),
        tap(() => console.warn("END")),
    );

    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter(e => e instanceof ChildActivationEnd && e.snapshot.component === this.route.component),
        buffer(routeEndEvent$),
        map(([ev]) => (ev as ChildActivationEnd).snapshot.firstChild.data),
        takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe$)
      )
      .subscribe(childRoute => {
        console.log('childRoute', childRoute);
      })
  }
```

- `routeEndEvent$` is an observable that will emit only when the route is ready(`NavigationEnd`)
- `filter(e => e instanceof ChildActivationEnd && e.snapshot.component === this.route.component)`: after examining a while the events emitted by the router, I reached this solution to determine whether the component(`HelloComponent`) is the parent(`this.route.component`) of the route which changed(`e.snapshot.component`).
- `buffer(routeEndEvent$)`: we only want to act when the router reached its final state(`NavigationEnd`). [here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/buffer) you can read more about the `buffer` operator

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-routes-and-modules?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

Comment: Was experiencing a similar issue where the url would change but the activated route wouldn't react. Forcing a reload of the page based on router event subscriptions helped unblock me

Comment: This looked like what I wanted, but didn't work. first run when the childComponent is activated (using routerLink="child"  in html) the parent component updates the childRoute, but not when the route is changed to "/parent" (using routerLink=""  in html). 
(my mistake.. I should use routerLink=".." to navigate up. ) =D

Comment: using routerLink=".." still doesn't do it for me. :/

Comment: Hi @JimiSweden, could you create a StackBlitz app with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, which was fixed when I subscribed to the "data" property of ActivatedRoute. Below is an example.

**Component:**

```
constructor (private route: ActivatedRoute)  {
        this.route.data.subscribe(({ listData }) => {
        this.listData = listData
    })
}
```

**Route:**

```
{
    path: ':id',
    component: Component,
    resolve: {
        listData: ModuleService
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using the firstChild attribute of the ActivatedRoute.

```
this._route.firstChild?.paramMap
  .subscribe((paramMap) => {
    console.log('Params: ', paramMap);
  });
```

It returns another ActivatedRoute object reference to the child route, which is the route that actually have the param.